# get Id of link and open alert javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found this example to open an alert in javascript as

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert("You have clicked Button " + clicked_id);
}
```

```html
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Button 1</button>
<button id="2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Button 2</button>
<button id="3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Button 3</button>
```

I'm confused about how to get this desired behavior when clicking on a link, I've tried in following way

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert("You have clicked Link " + clicked_id);
}
```

```html
<a id="1" href="javascript:reply_click(this.id);">Link 1</a>
<a id="2" href="javascript:reply_click(this.id);">Link 2</a>
<a id="3" href="javascript:reply_click(this.id);">Link 3</a>
```

when I try this code I get result as

```
You have clicked Link undefined
```

could not find way to get rid of `undefined` and get actual `id` of the link!

Comment: In the second example, `javascript` is the [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and `this` refer to the `Window` object.

Comment: OK any solution please!

Comment: Use `addEventListener` to bind events. CLEAN. OR use jQuery `$('a_selector').click(function() { alert(this.id); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert("You have clicked Link " + clicked_id);
}
```

```html
<a id="1" href="#" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Link 1</a>
<a id="2" href="#" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Link 2</a>
<a id="3" href="#" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you use attribute href with javascript in label (javascript:), the variable **this** refere to Window and dont to element. Whether you use the onClick attribute, the variable **this** will have the element object.

You can use onclick attribute in anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Change code like this :

```
<a id="1" onclick="reply_click(this.id)" href="#">Link 1</a>

<a id="2" onclick="reply_click(this.id)" href="#">Link 2</a>

<a id="3" onclick="reply_click(this.id)" href="#">Link 3</a>
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a id="1" onclick="reply_click(this.id)" href="#">Link 1</a>

    <a id="2" onclick="reply_click(this.id)" href="#">Link 2</a>

    <a id="3" onclick="reply_click(this.id)" href="#">Link 3</a>
    
    <script>
        
        function reply_click(clicked_id) {
            
            alert("You have clicked Link " + clicked_id);
            
            
        }
    </script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert("You have clicked Link " + clicked_id);
}
```

```html
<a id="1" onclick="reply_click(this.id);" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a id="2" onclick="reply_click(this.id);" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a id="3" onclick="reply_click(this.id);" href="#">Link 3</a>
```

You need to put the javascript function into the event `onclick` instead `href`, `href` is used to indicate the URL to which the link points.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
 <a id = "1" href= "#" >Link 1 </a>
<a id = "2" href= "#" >Link 2 </a>
<a id = "3" href= "#" >Link 3 </a>
 <script>
document. addEventListener("click",function(ev){
alert(ev.target.id);
});
</script>
```